# Locally remove definition of function

Tags: scoping

Consider the following code

```
g[x_]:=x^2
f[x_]:=2*g[x]
f[x] (* returns 2 x^2*)
test[x_]:=Module[{g},f[x]]
test[x] (* returns 2 x^2 as well*)
```

What I would like to have and the reason why I thought module would have been fine to use is to locally remove the definition of g so that test[x] returns me 2*g[x].

I want to do it by only modifying what appears inside the definition of my function test[x], I don't have the right to modify the definitions of f or g.

How is it possible to do it ?

Comment: You could try using `Block[{g = Inactive[g]}, f[x]]` instead of `Module[{g},f[x]]`. The Module variable `g` has no relationship to the function `g`.

Comment: I see a problem here. Even if you mange to keep g unevaluated inside test, as soon as test returns g, g will be evaluated if you have a definition like:"g[x_]:=x^2"